# UIVisualEffectView as input view for textfield in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, inputview, uivisualeffectview

I want to program a custom view as the input view for a textfield. This custom keyboard is a UIVisualEffectView with a blur effect, but when the keyboard shows up, the background isn't transparent, it's opaque.

When I add the keyboard as a subview and not as a input view, the effect works.

How can I assign the input view with a transparent effect?

```
textfield.inputview = visualeffectview;
```

Thank You